# flatMap in dask

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask

Many functional languages define `flatMap` function which works like `map` but can *flatten* returning values.
Spark/pyspark has it http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.flatMap

what would be the best way to have it in dask? 
My code looks like this:

```
import dask.bag as db
import json
from tools import get_records

records = db.read_text(json_file).map(json.loads).map(get_records)
```

`get_records` returns list of dicts. I just need to chain them into one sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want the [.flatten method](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.Bag.flatten)

```
In [1]: import dask.bag as db

In [2]: b = db.from_sequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [3]: def f(i):
   ...:     return list(range(i))
   ...: 

In [4]: b.map(f).compute()
Out[4]: [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]

In [5]: b.map(f).flatten().compute()
Out[5]: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So instead of a joined "flatMap" operation there are two operations "map" and "flatten" that you can use individually or chain as you prefer.